# how to use ng-controller from another ng-app?

Tags: angularjs

I am here for asking about ng-controller use for two ng-app which is not nested with each other, there are two different ng-app, and i have a question to ask is how to access control from the ng-controller of first ng-app to the second one?

```
<div ng-app="firstOne">
<div ng-controller="contrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="sender_Name"/>
</div>
</div>
<div ng-app="secondOne">
<div ng-controller="contrl">
<h2>{{sender_Name}}</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put countries.json file in data directory,this directory should be in app folder or script folder.like this:

- app

  - css
  - partial
  - js
  - index.html
  - data

    - countries.json

and then replace this part of code:

```
$http.get('data/countries.json').success(function(data){

      $scope.countries=data;
      })
   .error(function(error){
       console.log(error);
   })

});
```

and other controller like this:

```
countryAp.controller('countryDetail',function($scope,$routeParams){
     $scope.name=$routeParams.countryName;
});
```

Comment: 1.uncaught SysntaxError 2.Uncaught Error:[$injector:modulerr]

Comment: use edited code. ihave not mention 2nd controller.you have used $routeProvider.it should be $routeParams to access parameter from route.

Comment: that is not my problem, my problem is based on json file didnot work in this code, it didnot get into the code.

Comment: when i check the network next to the elements, there is no json file there,

Comment: you  have to add that file reference  in index.html

Comment: i think you are not putting json file at the right place.please see my code and try..

Answer (score 0):

You can't ask for contents of the file on the file system with a JavaScript application. AngularJS has nothing to do with it. Browsers simply won't let you do it, because it would be a tremendous security flaw.

Think about it - you go to my page "you-have-been-hacked.com" where **MY** script loops through all your personal documents and silently sends them over to my remote application. You wouldn't even know it! That is why browsers won't let you do it.

To play around with Angular and JSON, consider using some third party API that uses JSON (like [Twitter REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api)) or publish your JSON file on local Apache server. You can learn this way.